# Is it good etiquette to gg the opponent when they gg you, even if you haven't won yet?

Tags: mtg-arena, etiquette

Say you have some strong board position and are clearly winning, but you have not won yet. Opponent ggs you (i.e. uses the in-game 'good game' command). Should you gg back?

For context: you are winning, but not won yet. For example, you might have 10 power worth of attackers and opponent is on 12 life with no board and no cards in hand, but they do have [Wrath of God](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wrath%20of%20God), in their deck and if they just topdeck the wrath then they're right back in the game. They also have two draw steps to find the Wrath, since you do not presently have lethal on board.

It seems to me that most players gg the opponent right before they concede, but not always, and in the situation above they ought to not concede (unless they are on tilt, I guess).

Comment: Do people do this in chess / 9LX ?

Comment: Usually people use gg as well when they think they can't win. While your example still has a win/ turnaround condition, in an online game where people are quick to jump to a new game, there is the possibility that otherwise you would not even notice the gg since it gets lost in victory message/ restart. So a tiny bit early gg will make sure that the opponent sees it. And you can always thank them for a good game, even if it is not over yet

Comment: I think this is a question about your personality, not etiquette.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy There are definitely _some_ generally accepted standards for the use of emotes on Arena; that is pretty much the definition of "etiquette".

Comment: I often gg when I think I'm going to win. Sometimes I'm completely wrong and opponent has a wrath or somehow scrape through and turn the board around, and that's funny. On the other hand, if I see opponent has a cool combo I often let them play it out. If I've got a powerful combo it's a little disappointing when opponent concedes before I can really blow up.

Comment: @MatthewJensen gg'ing when in a winning position is generally considered bad etiquette on Arena. (No point debating this with me by the way: I don't necessarily agree with it, but it's the way it is).

Comment: @PhilipKendall I will definitely take that on board. I don’t play seriously enough to know the etiquette.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: Arena emotes, beyond maybe one "Hello" at the start of the match, are a touchy area all round. I'd honestly advise either just turning them off or ignoring them; nobody will criticise you for doing that.

With that out of the way, there is nothing wrong with replying "Good game" when an opponent says the same to you. If they're not immediately (as in "before taking any more game actions") conceding after their "Good game", they are breaching what etiquette does exist.

Similarly, I wouldn't worry about *why* they're conceding: maybe they're just grinding out their 15 daily wins and want to get to the next game as soon as possible, maybe their dinner was ready and they had to leave.